# Error Status code 401 message Unauthorized

Tags: typescript, authentication, nestjs

I am trying to implement auth following the [nest documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication)

My user.service.ts is:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

// This should be a real class/interface representing a user entity
export type User = any;

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  private readonly users = [
    {
      userId: 1,
      username: 'john',
      password: 'changeme',
    },
    {
      userId: 2,
      username: 'maria',
      password: 'guess',
    },
  ];

  async findOne(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return this.users.find(user => user.username === username);
  }
}
```

user.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Module({
  providers: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
auth.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {}

  async validateUser(username: string, pass: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findOne(username);
    if (user && user.password === pass) {
      const { password, ...result } = user;
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

auth.module.ts is

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';

@Module({
  imports: [UsersModule],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Then I implemented the local authentication strategy by using Passport-local:

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super();
  }

  async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(username, password);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

auth.module.ts is:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [UsersModule, PassportModule],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}

app.controller.ts is:
import { Controller, Request, Post, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post('auth/login')
  async login(@Request() req) {
    return req.user;
  }
}
```

But when I try to test whether the authentication is working fine bu running

```
$curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/auth/login -d '{"username": "john", "password": "changeme"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I get `{"statusCode":401,"message":"Unauthorized"`. I tried searching over the internet and found some [github link](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/3631). But that does not solve my problem either. I am following the doc. as it is, don't know where I am making any problems.
My working env is MacOS node version `v19.0.1`. Before it was `18.6` I upgraded to 19.0.1 but error persisted.

Comment: Do you have a reproduction repository with this? What you've shown looks correct

Comment: Is there any way you could tell me the mistake that I could be doing here

Comment: My only thought is the token you are sending is invalid. Would need a way to reproduce the error.